# Is ensemble model black box?

Tags: ensemble

Does all ensemble model variants such as voting, bagging and stacked considered black-box model? Since it is difficult to visualize and interpret the model especially when complexity increases?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: They kind of are in that you do not have a quantifiable attribution for each input variable. But you can get a variable importance list and some explanations depending on what platform and packages you use to build the models. So, you will not know what specifically makes this model tick, you can estimate the importance of a variable.